# Laravel 5.2 - Get Query String

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-string

How can I get the query string from a url in my blade template? For example if I have the following query string:

```
search?foo[]=1&foo[]=2&bar[]=1
```

I try to append it to a link in my blade template as follows:

```
<a href="/saved-search/create?{{ http_build_query(app('request')->query()) }}">
   Set up saved search
</a>
```

But this generates a query string by including the array indexe numbers as follows:

```
foo[0]=1&foo[1]=2&bar[0]=1
```

How can I get a query string as per the original url?

Comment: maybe `request()->all()` ?

Comment: Try this `echo (Request::getPathInfo() . (Request::getQueryString() ? ('?' . Request::getQueryString()) : '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`getQueryString`](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getQueryString) method.

```
<a href="/saved-search/create?{{ app('request')->getQueryString() }}">
   Set up saved search
</a>
```

It returns a ready-to-go urlencoded string:

```
string(35) "bar%5B%5D=1&foo%5B%5D=1&foo%5B%5D=2"
```

Also it's always possible to use the default PHP [`$_SERVER`](https://secure.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php) array:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

>>> string(23) "foo[]=1&foo[]=2&bar[]=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="{{ url('/saved-search/create', app('request')->query()) }}">
      Set up saved search
</a>
```